# Entered text in EditText not aligned properly

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

I have used EditText in my application, the problem is the entered text is not aligned properly, check it out my screen shot for what exactly my issue is.

[image]

My EditText XML file is

```
 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/signupFullName"
                    android:layout_width="179dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/updatedprofieledit"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/enterfullanme"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:singleLine="true" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
```

Kindly help me to clear this issue, have tried with some EditText Specification but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please upload the .xml file's code ?

Comment: add the padding for the edit-text.

Comment: There is a problem with your `EditText` background. using padding is not a good solution...

Comment: I have used diff edittext background in my app, this issue occurs in all cases.

Comment: @Brindha As gopal said padding is not good idea.take your background image as a 9 patch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your background image is smaller than your hard-coded width. Adding padding reserves some "unused room" at the end of your EditText. It would be better if you converted your background image to a 9-patch image so that it could resize automatically.

Answer (score 1):

add this line into your edit text

```
 android:padding="5dp"
```

Comment: It works, but can you explain, how the padding prevents Exceeding of text in EditText?

Comment: actually in edit text by default text start from its boundary itself so padding means some margin from inside like your text with will in edit box start from some distance which is padding and if u give  android:padding direct then it will take padding from right left top bottom all side padding :)

Comment: actually android:margin take distance of from its view itself from parent view and padding take a some distance from its view only like now your text start from some distance from edit text its padding

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
android:paddingRight="10dip"
```